# How do you remove dot net maui splash screen

Tags: c#, .net, mobile, maui

I would like to completely remove the dot net maui splash screen
I already know how to change it but I don't know how to remove it as commenting out the following code just removes the picture but the blue color is still there, actually the splash screen remains there. How do we  remove it completely?

Comment: what do you expect to display while the app is being loaded?

Comment: What is supposed to happen without a splash screen? Do you need this for Android or iOS or both? You should consider a simple modification of the splash screen to just show a colored background without a logo instead of removing the splash screen entirely.

Comment: I remember a time, when I would put significant effort to create a splash screen while loading. Why do you want to remove it, and what you think it will happen?

Answer (score 3):

For Android, you set this in the MainActivity.cs file (Platforms/Android):

```
[Activity(
    //Theme = "@style/Maui.SplashTheme",
    Theme = "@style/Maui.MainTheme.NoActionBar",
    MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize)]
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
```